# Selenium, Python, Marionette certificate warning

Tags: python, selenium, ssl, firefox

I am attempting to automate the push of a backup file from a (local) **headless** data server, to a (remote) **secure** backup server - which [for reasons] (currently) needs to be done via a web page.

I have written a Selenium/Python script which works well, but ignores ALL certificate errors - which, in this case, is NOT the desired behaviour.

- Platform: Raspberry Pi 3B / Raspbian 10
- Selenium: v3.141.0 (from Raspbian repo)
- Geckdriver: v0.29 (built from github release source with rust v1.50)
  ...Installed with:  `cp  /path/to/geckodriver-0.29.0/target/debug/geckodriver  /usr/local/bin`
- Firefox: v78.7.0esr (from Raspbian repo)

Most people (in my searches) seem to have the exact /opposite/ problem - IE. they want to DISable the security mechanism ...But inverting the (literally True/False) logic in those many different solutions has NOT led me to a solution which allows me to ENable cert checking.

Here is some (abbreviated and annotated) example code, with one of my (many) attempts:

```py
#!/bin/python3

from selenium import webdriver  # selenium instance
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options  # headless
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities  # Reject bad SSL

# Set headless mode
opts = Options()
opts.headless = True

# Enforce certificate checking - [this fails]
caps = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX
print(caps)  # {'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': True}
caps['acceptInsecureCerts'] = False
print(caps)  # {'browserName': 'firefox', 'marionette': True, 'acceptInsecureCerts': False}

driver = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities=caps, options=opts)

# LOG FILE ENTRY APPEARS in geckodriver.log:
# "Marionette  WARN  TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session"

driver.get("https://wrong.host.badssl.com")

# <<perform upload here>>

driver.save_screenshot("test.png")  # Page was NOT blocked! :(

driver.close()
```

My question is:
What modification(s) can be made to this code such that the `<<upload>>` will happen if (and only if) the SSL/TLS certificates are valid?

Extra kudos for an additional line of code to display a reason {"self-signed cert", "cert revoked", etc} if the `<<upload>>` is blocked.

Comment: You're only vulnerable if you installed a weird cert.

Comment: @pguardiario Installing a weird CA will not circumvent "Invalid CN" [common name] (as per the example code) ...When you run the example code, is your screenshot a 'certificate error' screen, or a yellow-on-red warning message?

Comment: I'm saying you're not vulnerable to MitM unless you (or someone else) decided to trust that cert. AFAIK you can't even disable security in Firefox if you wanted to (you can in chrome)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
capabilities = webdriver.DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
capabilities['acceptInsecureCerts'] = False
capabilities['marionette'] = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(desired_capabilities=capabilities)


# LOG FILE ENTRY APPEARS in geckodriver.log:
# "Marionette  WARN  TLS certificate errors will be ignored for this session"

driver.get("https://wrong.host.badssl.com")
```

You should use desiredcapability , use the above code

Comment: Sadly this does not work. I added the headerless code [required]. And therefore had to add `, options=opts` to the `Firefox()` call. I also added a `screenshot()` to the end... The gecko logfile still shows the WARNing. And the page is still successfully retrieved :(

Comment: Use the code as it  si , just copy paste it . If you don't want certificate error change acceptfert to true .

Comment: Sadly, your unmodified script does not work [it requires a head - which this server does not have] ...Selenium: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1" ...gecko: "Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified"

Comment: That's what you wanted right ,? The script to fail ?